# update a mysql table from a php page

Tags: php, mysql

Just a quick and simple question:
I am using php and am looking to update a field with values from a field in another table.
I have the syntax working fine in mysql, but can't seem to get it right in php.
example

```
tbl_1:
UID    |    Message    |    customer_email

tbl_2
AccountNumber    |    customer_email

update tbl_1 
set tbl_1.Message = REPLACE(Message,'FOO',AccountNumber) 
from 
tbl_1 inner join tbl_2 on tbl_1.customer_email = tbl_2.customer_email;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't used REPLACE() (much) in MySQL, but generally any query that runs on the SQL console should run via PHP.  What do you mean by "can't seem to get it right" - are you getting an error?  If so, post it.

Comment: No error is being shown, i';m just not getting the table update to happen.

Comment: care to share your current php code?

Comment: In that case you're definitely going to need to post code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "update tbl_1  set tbl_1.Message = REPLACE(Message,'FOO',AccountNumber)  from  tbl_1 inner join tbl_2 on tbl_1.customer_email = tbl_2.customer_email; ";   
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die("$sql: " . mysql_error());
```

Your query should work as is.  The PHP doesn't manipulate the SQL, it just passes it on.

Also, remember that if you are passing user input to the database, always sanitize it (or use PDO and save yourself).

Comment: My code is<?php


$db1 = mysql_connect ('localhost','username','password');


//Update the pending records with personalisation
$query1 = "update `tbl_1` set message = REPLACE(message,'#####',customer_id) from `tbl_1`inner join `tbl_2` on `tbl_1`.`email` = `tbl_2`.`email`;";

$res1 = mysql_query($query1, $db1);


exit;
?>

Comment: Got it fixed now - seems silly really:

    $query1 = "update DatabaseName.tbl_1 inner join DatabaseName.tbl_2 on tbl_1.email = tbl_2.email set message = replace(message,'#####',customer_id)";

Seems to be either capitalisation issue on the word replace or the last of a database name withinthe query itself.

Comment: Oh yay, if you have 2 databases open... should have thought of that

Comment: don't get why though, they are both in the same database :-)